# I am new to shiny and i try to build an application for registerInputHandler

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

i get the following error
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4864
Error in registerInputHandler("mypackage.validint", function(x, shinysession,  :   There is already an input handler for type: mypackage.validint
server.R
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
registerInputHandler("mypackage.validint", function(x, shinysession, name) {if (is.null(x)) return(NA)
 round(x)
})})